# About the POST_SET_DATA

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

`POST_SET_DATA` is supposed to be used to add or modify values to a form after submitting it, but I dont know exactly how to use it..

I have this code: http://pastebin.com/E9V9QHFn but I get `NULL end`, and it is for sure that data form is being submitted.

Here the code:

```
        //CustomerType.php
        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA,
            function(FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $data = $event->getData();
                var_dump($data);
                die("end");
            }
        );
```

Im following [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html).

My target this time is to set the value of a foreign key defined in the entity but not shown in the form, exactly the id of the logged user.

Comment: @zinweb have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to try this

```
  $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function(FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $form->getData();
            var_dump($data);
            die("end");
        }
    );
```

you've called getData() into the FormEvent. to get data you have to make $form->getData().

sorry im talking about your EventListener:

```
            $data = $form->getData();
```

not

```
            $data = $event->getData();
```

To get submitted data use PRE_SUBMIT/POST_SUBMIT instead of POST_SET_DATA

Comment: thanks, but I get the same output.. As I said before the server is reciving the data, Im checking using this: http://pastebin.com/Y4Aa5L5V

Comment: `if ($form->isValid())` should be in the controller, not the form type.

Comment: @n.1 yes, I have it in the controller

Comment: @Amine I have the same output

Comment: To get the submitted data, you have to use PRE_SUBMIT/POST_SUBMIT not POST_SET_DATA